# Magento 2: Suggestion to speed up minicart quantity update

Tags: magento2.2

I have changed minicart quantity plus, minus button to update the cart in real time.

[image: Minicart]

These buttons update cart by making an ajax call.

This round trip to the server takes time and user experience is bad if they click plus or minus with repeatedly very quickly.

Any suggestion to handle this user experience issue?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'll Suggest , that instead of doing ajax call on each button click, make button click and change by php code , and on proceed to checkout make final ajax call to update values as per user wants, it will reduce the time response time